# Save playlist position in VLC player

Tags: vlc-media-player, playlists

How do I make VLC player save my position in a playlist (with audio files) so that when I re-open the playlist it starts where I left off?

Comment: can it remember at least the (last used)  playlist as such?

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/226397/can-vlc-remember-movie-position (but not a dupe, the other Q is about remembering position within a single media file, not in a playlist)

Answer (score 4):

[This VLC addon](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/Remember+position?content=157838) is supposed to do something similar. For me it did not work, but it may be a first step.

As far as I can tell, VLC cannot even remember the last playlist used, according to [this](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=105473).

Comment: see http://superuser.com/a/540138/16966 for some info which may help in getting the lua addon working